# Can't add menu item in admin menu in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

I am trying to add test menu item in admin menu in magento 2, like it is described here: [Adding a Menu to the Left Side](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_admin_menu_items/) but menu item is not showing. What I miss or doing wrong ? Extension is enabled, cache disabled, commands executed:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

**/app/code/Rockforweb/Stuller/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Rockforweb_Stuller::top_level_example"
             title="Top Level Example"
             module="Rockforweb_Stuller"
             sortOrder="9999"
             resource="Magento_Backend::content"
            />
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd imagine that you have forgotten to add the etc/acl.xml file

If should look something like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                    <resource id="Rockforweb_Stuller::top_level_example" title="Your title" translate="title" />
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </config>
```

You would then need to change `resource="Magento_Backend::content" to resource="Rockforweb_Stuller::top_level_example"`

Run bin/magento setup:upgrade, logout and log back in again

Comment: Hello, thank you for answer. Unfortunatelly menu is not showing. When i run upgrade command i receive error from another extension: >> Incorrect dependency in class ... << maybe menu is not showing due to this error ?

Comment: you were right about acl.xml file....i didnt have it...now i have in etc/ folder

Comment: Sounds like a different error unrelated toy our xml. Have you got a di.xml file you could share ? I would also update your question with the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code and run the setup upgrade and deploy commands.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
<add id="Rockforweb_Stuller::top_level_example" title="Top Level Example" module="Rockforweb_Stuller" sortOrder="9999"          resource="Rockforweb_Stuller::top_level_example" />
</menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. Unfortunatelly it's not helps. Maybe because i don't have ACL ? or maybe i don't have recource model mentioned in your answer >>resource="Rockforweb_Stuller::top_level_example"<<